# How to fix build error converting YAML to JSON?

Tags: git, docker, heroku

The following happens when I do `git push heroku master`

```
Enumerating objects: 96, done.
Counting objects: 100% (96/96), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (94/94), done.
Writing objects: 100% (96/96), 37.53 KiB | 1.50 MiB/s, done.
Total 96 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: === Fetching app code
remote: 
remote: =!= Build failed due to an error:
remote: 
remote: =!= validate step: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 11: mapping values are not allowed in this context
remote: 
remote: If this persists, please contact us at https://help.heroku.com/.
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to mighty-stream-60397.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/mighty-stream-60397.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mighty-stream-60397.git'
```

I have two yml files, one is heroku.yml and the other is docker-compose.yml

```
setup:
  addons:
  - plan: heroku-postgresql

build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile

release:
  image:web
  command:
    - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

run:
  web: python manage.py runserver
```

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:2.8
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/


volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I'm not sure where the problem is? docker-compose can build the file so I'm guessing the problem is in heroku.yml, but I've tried deleting line 11, commenting it out, and it's still failing. I'm really new to this stuff and I honestly have no idea what is going on here. Help? thanks so mch

edit: This is what's in my build log (exact same error)

```
=== Fetching app code
=!= Build failed due to an error:
=!= validate step: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 11: mapping values are not allowed in this context
If this persists, please contact us at https://help.heroku.com/.
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I still don't quite understand what happend, but deleting `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` worked for me. My docker-compose file had no problem at all - though it should be noted that using the runserver command is also not a great idea. I ended up switching to daphne and my super simple heroku.yml looks like this

```
setup:
  addons:
  - plan: heroku-postgresql

build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile

release:
  image: web

run:
  web: daphne test_project.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
```

which works! Hope this can help anyone